# Drive 4 DC motors off a dual drive motor controller

Tags: dc-motor, robotics, motor-controller, brushed-dc-motor

I'd like to build a 4-wheel skid steer robot. I have selected [this motor](http://www.superdroidrobots.com/shop/item.aspx?itemid=840) and [this motor controller](http://www.basicmicro.com/Robo-Claw-2x10A_p_45.html).

The motor controller can handle a 10A draw and has the ability to operate over serial TTL and give me encoder feedback (which is what I want).

The motor controller is designed to drive two motors (not four). I know that I can link two motor controllers together (one for left wheels and one for right) — but is that necessary? I mean the motors are rated at 2300mA max and the motor controller is 10A. Would it be a bad idea to simply connect two motors to channel A and the other two to channel B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody better qualified has answered, I'll take a crack at this one.

Simply looking at the current draw, it looks OK.  But it's close enough that you might want to verify the current draw just in case the motor makers took a little "creative license" with the specs.  Check the current under both no load and max load.

But, what I would be most concerned with is the speed of the motors.  It's almost certain that two motors will not be matched in speed.  And even if they are, they won't stay that way due to age, wear, and differences in weight distribution and terrain.

This difference in speed, especially with a geared motor that won't tend to slip, will manifest itself as stearing problems, increased wear on the wheels, and other bad things.

But, assuming that the current spec is correct, I don't see any harm in just trying it.  There is a chance that I'm wrong and they will be matched enough that it'll work just fine.